# What's a good strategy for managing static data in an SOA?

Tags: rest, soa, configuration-management

I'm working on a web application that sits on top of a number of RESTful web services, interacting primarily with those services through JSON formatted messages over HTTP. Our application has a great deal of static data that are read from these services (internationalization lookups, configuration, etc.) during operation.

Unfortunately, we work pretty closely with the team who develops the webservces, so we know the backend architecture fairly intimately. Most of the services are using a MongoDB store for persistence, and our strategy thus far for managing the static data we require to be loaded is to utilize MongoDB dumps committed to version control that are loaded at deploy/upgrade time.

We'd like to decouple our static data from the persistence store. The best ideas that have come forth thus far mostly involve storing static data formatted as it would be passed to services (JSON files) and then writing a "loader" process/script that will live as part of the deployment process which will interact with services to load the data.

Are there patterns/strategies for managing/loading/deploying "application" data to services?

Comment: can you have a comprehensive config REST call with all the static data that you load once when the application starts? rather than calling them every time you need it.

Comment: I think the best suggestion we've heard thus far is to have at least one bulk POST endpoint per data category for creation, potentially with a flag for "overwrite if present" type operations.

I guess the RESTful way would be to POST an message containing an array of all values to the root resource URI. I'm not sure about the RESTful way to handle the "the value already exists" scenario.

Comment: Some other helpful questions:

- [Bulk Collection Manipulation through a REST (RESTful) API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306271/bulk-collection-manipulation-through-a-rest-restful-api)
- [What's the best practice for initial (bulk) data import into RESTful system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895505/whats-the-best-practice-for-initial-bulk-data-import-into-restful-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you're approaching the problem correctly.  Add a layer of abstraction between your database and static data so that the receiver always gets the same thing.  It may require a little rewiring, but the end effect is that the back end can change any number of ways but the front end still gets the same format everytime.

I don't know what language/libraries you're using to convert to JSON, but I would recommend [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) if you're using Java since it has a system to convert any object into a JSON counterpart.  With the help of annotations, you can also control which properties you want to be converted into JSON.